Movie about escaping a cryosleep prison
I think it's a drama/action movie from the 90's; it was on tv when I was a child. It's not Demolition Man, but it's similar.
So, the plot twist: In the future a man (I think he was a cop) goes to prison for something I think he didn't do. It's like a cryosleep prison or just sleep prison but he was there 15 or 20 years. He awakes and escapes from prison using a holographic thing. But he's caught by futuristic cops in a metro. He escapes 3 times (I think) and the last time he calls his daughter and she's 80 years old. 
So this is all I can remember. Hope you guys can help me.

I think you're looking for Spoiler from 1998.

Roger Mason is a prisoner locked away in a futuristic fortress of a jail. Desperate to escape and see his daughter, he keeps making attempt after attempt to break free, but each one is foiled just as he's about to gain his freedom. As his punishments include being frozen in suspended animation for years at a time, he stays the same age while his daughter grows older. 



@alex No problem, but please don't forget to click on the check mark to mark it as closed.
